# Simple controller not working

Tags: module, magento-1, controllers

I am learning to make sense of magento and i am stuck.I have different stores and i am creating a controller but it seem it is not working and giving 404. 
Following is my code 
config.xml under /app/code/local/Ammardotcom/Helloworld/etc

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ammardotcom_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and under app/etc/modules/ Ammardotcom_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ammardotcome_Helloworld>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ammardotcome_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

while my file is called IndexController.php and it has following code under /app/code/local/Ammardotcom/Helloworld/controllers/

```
class Ammardotcome_Helloworld_IndexController
extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
}
```

The module shows in backend but isn't loading, i am following @Alan [tut](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world)

Comment: Is it not available at yoursite.com/helloworld/index/index ?

Comment: @philwinkle nope, it gives 404 page.

Comment: @Nofel try `yoursite.com/helloworld` your example works for me considering there are no XML errors.

Comment: @dchayka yes i tried that too but nothing, can it be because of multiple store setup? I don't think it should.

Comment: Please try with http://domain.com/index.php/ammardotcome/helloworld your code have no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of hair pulling, i found out the reason, i misspelled my node in comparison to my folder `namespace/module_name` where namespace was *`Ammardotcome`* and xml node was *`Ammardotcom`*

Comment: ahhh, one of those problems :) mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove blank spaces from start of your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ammardotcom_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

If you add blank spaces at the start of your xml file, it may not load.

Comment: No there is no spaces.

Comment: @Nofel update your question then - it's misleading

Comment: @RobbieAverill no, it is the same as i had problem with. Not misleading, the solution provided by me is a update to the question resulting in the question's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined module version in config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ammardotcome_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ammardotcome_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    .....
</config>
```

Comment: Tested this solution on 1.9.2.1 and still works without version defined. I was expecting it to fail :/ Interesting find.